# Insert an object in s3 folder conditionally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to insert an object in an s3 folder. But the insertion should be done only if the number of objects in that folder already present is less than 10. Also, I first need to check if the folder with a particular name exists. If not I have to create one. Is this possible using java?

eg: I have 5 records :-

```
1,abc,def

2,xyz,mno

1,ghi,lks

2,dec,frt

3,uhy,erw
```

Now I want to traverse each record line by line. The first values i.e. 1,2,3 in this case will be the name of s3 folders. The second will be object key and third the object value. So this means there will three folders 1,2,3 and they will store multiple corresponding objects.

```
      ---- abc.txt
1 ----|
      |
      ---- ghi.txt

      ---- xyz.txt
2 ----|
      |
      ---- dec.txt

3 ---- uhy.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the AWS SDK for Java

First, I would read though [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html) document-- this should help you get a better understanding of how objects are stored in S3.  Basically, there is no concept of a folder in s3 (aws console only presents objects as if they were in a traditional file system for UX).

**Proposed Methods:**

- For listing objects with a certain prefix, I would take a look at the [ListObjectsV2Request](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Request.html) method.
- For uploading an object, I would look at the methods available in the [PutObjectRequest](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html) class.

Hope this helps!  glhf